# In TabView the view pager does not remove the selected tab fragment, instead it removes the last tab fragment

Tags: java, android

In my activity i have tablayout, view pager, add tab and remove tab. Everything works fine but when I click on remove tab button i passing the selected tabs position but the last tab is getting deleted. When it comes to tab name selected tab name is getting deleted.

```
removeExpenseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (tabs.getTabCount() != 1) {
                    int i = tabs.getSelectedTabPosition();
                    modeAdapter.removeFragment(i);
                    viewPager.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
                    modeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    tabNameChanger();
                } else {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        });

static class PayModeAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public PayModeAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public void removeFragment(int position) {
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
        mFragmentList.remove(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}



private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        modeAdapter = new  ReqCreationActivity.PayModeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        modeAdapter.addFragment(new ReqDetailFragment(), "Expense");
        viewPager.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
        modeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: So position is correct? And it removes right tab, but wrong fragment?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky Exactly!

Comment: Strange. Could you show code of your modeAdapter?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky I've updated the code.

Comment: I think viewPager.setAdapter(modeAdapter); is not needed, it's enough just modeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); But I doubt that it is the cause...

Comment: What I would try - store mFragmentList and mFragmentTitleList inside your activity, not inside adapter. And when you remove element - set updated lists in adapter

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky didn't work